# Laravel / PHP - Advanced polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my web application, users can upload `documents` or `emails` to `channels`.

A channel can furthermore then have `document_tags` and `email_tags`, that **all** uploaded documents/emails automatically should inherit.

Furthermore, `document_tags` and `email_tags` **will** have different descriptions: `tag_descriptions`. So for example if we have a document, uploaded to a channel that have the tags: `animals (id = 1)` and `pets (id = 2)`

1. `Document #55` is upladed to `Channel #8`.
2. `Document #55` will automatically inherit the tags, that have `document_tags.channel_id = 55` (this can be accessed with the following relationship: `$channel->documenttags`). In this case `animals` and `pets`.
3. Now the user should be able to set an unique description for the tegs `animals` and `pets` in `tag_descriptions`, for example:

`tag_descriptions`

```
id | taggable_type   | taggable_id  | typeable_type | typeable_id | description
1  | App\DocumentTag | 1            |  App\Document | 55          | My unique description for animals. 
2  | App\DocumentTag | 2            |  App\Document | 55          | My unique description for pets.
```

Now in above database design the uploaded `document #55`, have the tags: `animals` and `pets` associated, but further these two tags have a unique description, that is unique for the specific **document**.

If I upload another document, or an email (let's say `email #20`), then I imagine it will look like:

`tag_descriptions`:

```
id | taggable_type   | taggable_id  | typeable_type | typeable_id | description
1  | App\DocumentTag | 1            |  App\Document | 55          | My unique description for animals. 
2  | App\DocumentTag | 2            |  App\Document | 55          | My unique description for pets.
3  | App\EmailTag    | 1            |  App\Email    | 20          | Another unique description for animals. 
4  | App\EmailTag    | 2            |  App\Email    | 20          | Yet another unique description for pets.
```

Now the `email #20` also have the tags `animals` and `pets`, but in this case, the user can set unique descriptions for the tags.

**Now my question is:**

Is above design doable, and is it considered best practice in Laravel / PHP? I am a bit unsure how to structure the code, because the `TagDescription` model will suddenly have **two polymorphic** relationships (`taggable` and `typeable`), and I cannot find anything in the documentation that this is supported.

Furthermore, I am unsure if I can use the above design to access the unique descriptions through the specific uploaded document, such as:

```
//In my Document.php model:
public function tagdescriptions()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TagDescription::class, 'typeable');
}
```

Then use it like: `$document->tagdescriptions`.

Last but not least - I am a bit unsure how to save the unique tag description for the specific taggable_id / taggable_type and unique email/document. (typeable_id and typeable_type).

Comment: This is a complex problem not directly solvable with Laravel's eloquent. You may find some inspiration in this post https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many and especially the Maxeee09 proposal called `HasManyThroughBelongsTo` model relation extension.

Comment: At a glance a pivot table to store all the polymorphic relations would be better.

Comment: Can the `document_tags` and `email_tags` of a channel change over time and what are the consequences for existing documents? This question should be answered both for new tags that are added as well as tags that are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but a table with two polymorphic relations doesn't make sense.  The table that enables the polymorphic relation is a pivot table. While I get that you want unique descriptions for each tag and relationship type, a pivot table should only have two foreign key columns, one the table relating to and relating from.
There is another way, which is to use the polymorphic relationship as a constraint on the pivot table.  To start with the pivot table in the polymorphic relationship should be renamed to "taggables".  You do not need a "email_tag" table and "document_tag" table, you can use a table called "tags".  To get a unique description for each tag, you can add the description to the table "tabblables".

The migration file looks like this....

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('taggable_id');
        $table->string('taggable_type');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('emails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here what you need to do in your email and document models.

```
class Email extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tags.
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->withPivot('description');
    }
}

class Document extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tag descriptions.
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->withPivot('description');
    }
}
```

The "withPivot" function will return the value of the column specified in the query.

Here is what you need to do in your Tags Model.

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tag descriptions.
     */
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphByMany(Document::class, 'taggable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the tag descriptions.
     */
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->morphByMany(Email::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

You do not need a "Taggables" table model.

Here is what is going.  When you tinker...

```
$email = App\Email::find(1)->tags;
```

This query will run...

```
select `tags`.*, 
    `taggables`.`taggable_id` as `pivot_taggable_id`, 
    `taggables`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`, 
    `taggables`.`taggable_type` as `pivot_taggable_type`, 
    `taggables`.`description` as `pivot_description` 
from `tags` 
inner join `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id` 
where `taggables`.`taggable_id` = 1 
and `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'App\Email'
```

What you see is the constraint of the polymorphic relationship can query the unique description.  In summing up, you can't put more than two foreign key relations in a pivot table, but you can add the constraint to your pivot table.

I think it looks cleaner to add this your AppServiceProvider.php file...

```
public function boot()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
        'email'     => Email::class,
        'document'  => Document::class
    ]);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

This will enable you to store a value of "email" or "document" as your taggable type.

For posting to the tables I think this looks the cleanest...

```
$tag = Tag::firstOrNew(["name"=>"#tag"]);
$tag->name = "#tag";

$document = new Document();
$document->name = "new doc";
$document->save();
$document->tags()->save($tag,["description"=>"some description"]);
```

You can certainly use attach(). Save() uses attach() as shown here...
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L871

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jed for the detailed answer! I have two questions though. When creating a Tag - this should be rather standard right? Just do a `create`. However, when I create a tag description, how would I do that?

Comment: So I tried a bit, and this seems to work:
`$document>tags()->attach($tag, ['description' => "Custom Tag Description"]);`

Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: I added to the answer to show how to post a new tag. Attach will work, but save I think is cleaner. One thing with save is that you need timestamps in your database schema.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've spent weeks trying to figure this out, and your solution works perfectly!!!